# Compare day only in array with ISO 8601 timestamps

Tags: jquery, timestamp

How can I compare the day only in ISO 8601 timestamps?
I'm trying to create a script which groups data by day. Right now it compares by the whole timestamp (date and time), but how can I change it to compare by date only?

Js:

```
  var newData = data.reduce(
    (acc, el) => {
      var date = el.commit.committer.date; // ISO 8601 timestamp
      var msg = el.commit.message;
      if (acc.hasOwnProperty(date))
        acc[date].push(msg);
      else
        acc[date] = [msg];
      return acc;
    }, {}
  )

  Object.keys(newData).forEach(function(v, k) {
    var date = v;
    var message = newData[v].join(", ");
    var t = new Date(date);
    $('body').append('<li>' + t + ': ' + message + '</li>');
  });
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lod24vb/26/).

Comment: jsfiddle.net/1Lod24vb/31

Have a look.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, man. Can you change your comment into an answer, please?

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you. Sure, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your comparison logic as well as the key...

http://jsfiddle.net/1Lod24vb/31

```
Have a look
```

Comment: Could you state here what was wrong, what you changed and why. That jsfiddle could go away and the answer will lose it's context.